# using EmbeddedChartBuilder and 'getting columns are out of bounds'

Tags: google-apps-script

This is my short function that keeps getting "Those columns are out of bounds"

```
function myFunction() {
var  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var chartBuilder = sheet.newChart();
chartBuilder.addRange(range).setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE).setOption('title', 'My Line Chart!');
sheet.insertChart(chartBuilder.build());
}
```

I've tried `sheet.getRange("A1:B6")` as well.

The 1st column are dates and the 2nd column are ints. The standard Insert a Graph GUI can use the data as is.

Has anybody had any success with the new EmbeddedGraph classes?
thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is not the input data range, but where the chart is being placed in the build process. It's attempting to put the chart on top of the data on the page. You need to use `setPosition` on the `chartBuilder` to tell where the chart should go. I believe it will try to put it at row 1, column 1 if you don't specify anything, which means it's likely trying to overwrite your data.

Try replacing your last line with this

```
sheet.insertChart(chartBuilder.setPosition(7, 1, 1, 1).build());
```

[setPosition](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#setPosition(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) parameters are: int Row, int Col, Row offset, Col offset.

Comment: @ScottR - I did approve your edit although I think it wasn't really necessary but if you think it makes it more explicit then why not ? The link to the doc is a good think , I should have done it ;-)

Comment: I had the same problem, but I just copied your code exactly and got the same error as the OP because my data was different. When I realized what the underlying issue was (chart location overwriting data), I figured it out. Hence I thought editing the answer might make it quicker for other folks like me!